# Implementing a nested class function in c++

Tags: c++

so thats what i got going.

```
template<class T>
class List{
    Node<T> head;
    int size;
public:
    class Iterator;

template <class T>
class List<T>::Iterator{
public:
Iterator& operator++();
```

i'm trying to implement like so:

```
template<class T>
typename List<T>::Iterator& List<T>::Iterator::operator++()
```

but it keeps telling me "Member declaration not found"

**EDIT:**
thats the entire relevent code:

```
template <class T>
class Node {
    T data;
    Node<T>* next;
public:
    Node () : next(0){};
    Node (const T& info, Node<T>* next = 0) : data(info), next(next){};
    friend class List<T>;
    friend class Iterator;
    friend class ConstIterator;
};

template<class T>
class List{
    Node<T> head;
    int size;
    void listSwap(Node<T>* node1, Node<T>* node2);
public:
    class Iterator;
    class ConstIterator;
    List ();
    List(const List<T>& list);
    List& operator=(const List<T>& list);
    ConstIterator begin() const;
    Iterator begin();
    ConstIterator end() const;
    Iterator end();
    void insert(const T& t);
    void insert(const T& t,const Iterator& it);
    void remove(const Iterator& it);
//  template<class Function>
//  ConstIterator find(Function f);
    template<class Function>
    Iterator find(Function f);
    template<class Function>
    void sort(Function f);
    int getSize();
    bool operator==(const List<T>& list2) const;
    bool operator!=(const List<T>& list2) const;
    ~List();
};

template <class T>
class List<T>::Iterator{
    List<T>* list;
    Node<T>* index;
public:
    Iterator(List<T> list);
    Iterator(List<T> list, Iterator& it);
    Iterator& operator++();
    Iterator operator++(int);
    T operator*();
    bool operator==(const Iterator& iterator2);
    bool operator!=(const Iterator& iterator2);
    ~Iterator();
    friend class List<T>;
};
```

thought I think it is ok :/
so frustrating sometimes....
Thank you guys for the help!

Comment: [There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with it](http://ideone.com/wnH6iT).

Comment: What is your compiler?

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė that is because you added a significant modification :-)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `template<class T> class List<T>::Iterator` in the `Iterator` class definition if iterator is a nested class. Just `class Iterator`.

```
template<class T>
class List{
  Node<T> head;
  int size;
public:

  class Iterator
  {
   public:
    Iterator& operator++();
   ....
  };
  ....
};
```

Either that, or you are missing the closing `};` of your `List` class:

```
template<class T>
class List{
    Node<T> head;
    int size;
public:
    class Iterator;
};
^^ HERE!
```

Answer (score 0):

I see some obvious bugs, as the class `List` is not closed before you define `List<T>::Iterator`, but I presume it is so because you cut off some portion of your code.

Unfortunately, I was unable to reproduce your case. The following code:

```
class List {
    int size;
public:
    class Iterator;
};

template <class T>
class List<T>::Iterator {
    public:
        Iterator& operator++();
};

template <class T>
typename List<T>::Iterator& List<T>::Iterator::operator++() {
    return *this;
}

int main() {
}
```

And it compiles just fine under g++ (4.6.3) and clang++ (3.1), so the problem is somewhere else which you are not showing us.

Answer (score 0):

You first code sample seems to be shreeded beyond recognition.

As for your second (longer) section of code, I don't see anthing wrong with it aside from one suspect area. Your `friend` declarations inside `Node` will refer to some non-template `Iterator` and `ConstIterator` classes from global namespace. Meanwhile, `Iterator` and `ConstIterator` from `List` are templates that do not belong to global namespace. Were those `friend` declarations in `Node` supposed to refer to `Iterator` and `ConstIterator` from `List` or not?